# Form submission with POST method is truncated in Firefox

Tags: java, forms, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I have an Struts 2 application running in `https`.

I have a large form with data size approx 8KB, where the back end object is binding from the front end. 
The form is submitted to the server properly in IE.

But when the form is submitted through Firefox then the data is not binding properly in the back end objects as well as the request method is truncated. we are submitting the form by using POST method but in server the method name is `'OST'`.

Ex :

```
 HttpServletRequest request;
 request.getMethod() return "OST"
```

form is submitting with java script and jquery

Ex :

```
var data = $('#regHHFormID').serialize();

$.get('activateProfile.action', data, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, "json");
```

Here is the sample data which is submitted to the server after serialize.

> household.status=0&dualActiveDutyfamilyTypeID=15&household.key=897788905893&household.createFrom=CONSUMER&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.type=SPONSOR&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileID=1847&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.profileNameID=1885&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.firstName=sss&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.middleName=&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.lastName=sss&household.password=111111111aA&password2=111111111aA&household.familyGroupID=1&household.familyTypeID=4&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.branchID=5&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.command=&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.type=SPOUSE&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.profileID=&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.profileNameID=&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.firstName=ss&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.middleName=rrr&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.lastName=sss&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.branchID=0&household.profileDatas%5B1%5D.command=&childProfile.profileNameData%5B0%5D.firstName=C4&childProfile.profileNameData%5B0%5D.middleName=CR&childProfile.profileNameData%5B0%5D.lastName=RG&childProfile.isUnBorn=false&birthDate=11.4.2013&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.questionID=1&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.profileIATAnswerID=&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.answer=false&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.answerDetails=Please+provide+information+that+will+help+us+support+your+child's+medical+needs.&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.questionID=2&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.profileIATAnswerID=&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.answer=false&childProfile.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.answerDetails=Please+describe+accommodations+necessary+to+help+this+child+participate+in+Child+and+Youth+Programs.&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileID=0&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.type=CHILD&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.profileNameID=&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.firstName=C4&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.middleName=CR&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileNameData%5B0%5D.lastName=RG&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.birthDateConsumer=11.4.2013&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.isUnBorn=false&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.editStatus=&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.questionID=1&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.profileIATAnswerID=&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B0%5D.answer=false&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.questionID=2&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.profileIATAnswerID=&household.profileDatas%5B2%5D.profileIATAnswerDatas%5B1%5D.answer=false&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressID=&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.typeCode=PRIMARY&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.line1=D&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.line2=F&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.city=F&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.stateCode=AL&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.zip=12323&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePostalAddressDatas%5B0%5D.countryCode=USA&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberID=0&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.phoneNumber=111.111.1111&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.typeCode=WORK&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.entityType=CONSUMER&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.entityID=0&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.belongsTo=1&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.editStatus=&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profilePhoneNumberDatas%5B0%5D.isPreferred=true&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressID=1232&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.emailAddress=ss%40fer.com&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.typeCode=PRIMARY&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.entityType=CONSUMER&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.entityID=1847&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.belongsTo=1&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.isNotify=true&household.profileDatas%5B0%5D.profileEmailAddressDatas%5B0%5D.editStatus=&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B0%5D.emailNotificationID=58&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B0%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B0%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B0%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B1%5D.emailNotificationID=59&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B1%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B2%5D.emailNotificationID=60&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B2%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B2%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B2%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B3%5D.emailNotificationID=61&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B3%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B3%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B3%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B4%5D.emailNotificationID=62&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B4%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B4%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B4%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B5%5D.emailNotificationID=63&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B5%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B6%5D.emailNotificationID=64&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B6%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B6%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B6%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B7%5D.emailNotificationID=65&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B7%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B7%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B7%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B8%5D.emailNotificationID=66&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B8%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B8%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B8%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B9%5D.emailNotificationID=67&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B9%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B9%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B9%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B10%5D.emailNotificationID=68&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B10%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B11%5D.emailNotificationID=69&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B11%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B11%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B11%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B12%5D.emailNotificationID=70&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B12%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B12%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B12%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B13%5D.emailNotificationID=76&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B13%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B13%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B13%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B14%5D.emailNotificationID=77&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B14%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B14%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B14%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B15%5D.emailNotificationID=71&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B15%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B15%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B15%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B16%5D.emailNotificationID=82&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B16%5D.isMandatory=false&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B16%5D.isSelected=true&__checkbox_household.emailNotificationDatas%5B16%5D.isSelected=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B17%5D.emailNotificationID=72&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B17%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B18%5D.emailNotificationID=73&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B18%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B19%5D.emailNotificationID=74&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B19%5D.isMandatory=true&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B20%5D.emailNotificationID=75&household.emailNotificationDatas%5B20%5D.isMandatory=true

I am not finding any clue why this is happening.

Comment: So, you want to say that IE work correctly, but Firefox  - not?

Comment: In IE/chrome its always working. But in Firefox, if the data size is too small then it is working. We are not getting success with our post data both in ajax post or direct form submit.

Answer (score 0):

If your `request.getMethod()` returns `"OST"` this means that a method is not a valid HTTP one. And the browser revert to default which is `"GET"`.

This method has bounds on data send in the URL. It could be limited by the length of the URL itself. Check the `<form>` tag or if you are using Ajax request the method `"POST"` is used to encapsulate the data with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery get method in turn calls the AJAX only. so you can think of using the AJAX api of Jquery

```
  $.ajax({
  url:"activateProfile.action"
  type: "POST",
  dataType : "json"
  data: data,
   success:function(data){
    console.log('in your success step');
   }
});
```

Make sure to declare the cache according to your usage. Hope this helps.